# Syntax highlighting in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express ed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

How can I see which file extensions are related to which kind of syntax highlighting? Unfortunately, `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extensions` lists only those entered manually, no default ones. And I didn't manage to find it on my own via Google or other means.

My particular problem is, I want to have .inc highlighted exactly as .asp but I'm not sure which editor is used for .asp. I did try the following (none worked):

- Web Form Editor
- VBscript Editor
- HTML Editor
- Script Editor

(They did work in a sense that they colored my code in one way or another, but it wasn't the same highlight as I get for `.asp` files).

Answer (score 0):

There are a security problem with non .asp files. The problem is that you can view the full code of the file if you access to the file directly in the URL.

Recommended workaround (that solves your problem as a bonus) is to create a identical .asp file and change the .inc file to includes the .asp file

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can't (probably due to the server configuration), .inc files are treated exactly as .asp. Though I'm aware of this security problem and for the time being I just rename files to .asp ;) Thank you Eduardo.

But my question still stays...